# Python and SQL: Getting rows from csv results in ERROR: "There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause."

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have a csv file with several records that I am trying to import into a SQL table via a Python script. My csv file (now reduced to) just one row of 1s. Here is what I am trying to do (after successfully connecting to the database etc etc...):

```
def add_records():
    with open('C:/testing/myCSV.csv') as csvFile:

        for row in csvFile:
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO MY_Table (thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5)"
                "VALUES (?)", row
            )
```

No matter how I format the data in the csv (right now it's all 1s) I get the error:

> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause

Comment: You need one `?` for every value in `row`.

Comment: Use ```VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)``` as you are inserting 5 values into the table.

Comment: @mechanical_meat for every target column, because parser knows nothing about`row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a value (or `?` placeholder) in the `values` clause for each column you're inserting:

```py
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO MY_Table (thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5)"
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", row
)
```

EDIT:
`row` is just a simple line read from a CSV file. You should probably use a [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to break it up to its individual components:

```py
with open('C:/testing/myCSV.csv') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO MY_Table (thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5)"
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", row
        )
```

Comment: @CJamesEd you aren't parsing the CSV. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('C:/testing/myCSV.csv') as csvFile:
    factories = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in factories:
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO MY_Table (thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5)"
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (''.join(row[0])), (''.join(row[1])), (''.join(row[2])), (''.join(row[3])), (''.join(row[4]))
        )
```